# .NET WebBrowser InvokeScript to submit and redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webbrowser-control

I'm developing an application in C# (using ASP .NET indeed). I'm using a WebBrowser control in which I insert a little HTML code (basically a form and a javascript function that only submits the form). The purpose of that form is to log in some web site (if I insert that HTML in a document and I open it on Chrome or IE, it works, i get to log in and it redirects me to the web site).

I need the WebBrowser control to log me in and redirect to the url pointed in the form action field as the real WebBrowser does, but it doesn´t seem to react to none of these commands:

- browser.Document.InvokeScript("Redirect");
- browser.Document.Forms[0].InvokeMember("submit");

I wait until DocumentCompleted is fired in order to avoid any problems with code not loaded yet. The code is basically this:

```
private void LogIn(string user, string pass)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(delegate()
        {
            using (WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser())
            {
                browser.AllowNavigation = true;
                browser.Visible = true;
                browser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(DocumentCompleted);
                var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                sb.AppendFormat("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">");
                sb.AppendFormat("<html style=\"position:relative;overflow: hidden;\">");
                sb.Append("<head>");
                sb.AppendFormat("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
                sb.Append("function Redirect(){");
                sb.AppendFormat("document.forms[0].submit();");
                sb.Append("}");
                sb.Append("</script>");
                sb.Append("</head>");
                sb.Append("<body onload=\"Redirect()\">");
                sb.AppendFormat("<form method=\"POST\" action=\"" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["URL_TEST"] + "\">");
                sb.AppendFormat("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"loginName\" id=\"loginName\" value=\"" + user + "\" />");
                sb.AppendFormat("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"password\" id=\"password\" value=\"" + pass + "\" />");
                sb.Append("</form>");
                sb.Append("</body>");
                sb.Append("</html>");
                browser.DocumentText = @sb.ToString();
                while (browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
                }
            }
        });
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
        thread.Join();
    }

private void DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser browser = sender as WebBrowser;
        browser.Visible = true;
        if (!browser.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("MyView"))
        {
            browser.DocumentCompleted -= new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(DocumentCompleted);
            browser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(DocumentCompleted);
            browser.Document.InvokeScript("Redirect");
            // browser.Document.Forms[0].InvokeMember("submit");
        }
        else
        {
            int  a = 1;
        }
    }
```

As I see it, DocumentCompleted should be called twice, once when I set the browser.DocumentText and other when it submits the form. The URL to which I should be redirected contains the word MyView, so the second time it gets called it should get into the else block. However, it only gets called once. Could I get any help on this? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: There were some times in which DocumentCompleted didnfire even once. After setting browser.visible to true, it always fires at least once.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem is with url which is at
  `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["URL_TEST"]` 
because at my form DocumentCompleted was called twice. One of the possible problems, which you can consider can be javascript errors at opened url, or something similar. 
 I just added button at form, and here is the code:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LogIn("", "");
        }

        private void LogIn(string user, string pass)
        {

                   .
                   . 
                   . 

        }

        private void DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            WebBrowser browser = sender as WebBrowser;
            if (!browser.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("MyView"))
            {
                browser.DocumentCompleted -= new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(DocumentCompleted);
                browser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(DocumentCompleted);
                browser.Document.InvokeScript("Redirect");
                // browser.Document.Forms[0].InvokeMember("submit");
            }
            else
            {
                int a = 1;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you! It isn't working yet, the URL is fine as it's the same I'm using in the plain HTML file I mentioned, and the javascript issue was something I considered yesterday (spent many hours trying to fix it and by the time I wrote this post I couldn't remember all of them, sorry about that). I tried with the WebKitBrowser control but it didn't work either.

Comment: Then I have another question for you. In code, which you presented you have following line: <body onload=Redirigir()>, but the function you declared is named function Redirect(){. Take notice in difference between Redirigir and Redirect. Your html has error, end due to that error is not executed twice.

Comment: My bad. I had part of my code in Spanish and I translated it here to make it more readable, but I'm afraid I forgot that line. I also realised that I forgot to close the body, I'll edit the question.

Comment: Can you still reproduce your bug?

Comment: Definitely, DocumentCompleted only fires once still... it seems that the InvokeScript doesn't do anything here

Comment: http://blog.zaletskyy.com/Media/Default/stackoverflow/WindowsFormsApplication1.zip it is zipped project. If you put brekpoint at DocumentCompleted you'll notice that it is fired twice

Comment: Thanks for your time, it doesn't work yet though, maybe it's really problem of the site I'm tryng to open...

Comment: Can you share url of site and username, password?

Comment: Sorry for the delay... I used the code in an MVC site and it worked, so I didn't do anything else. The url is local so it's impossible to share it. Thanks for your time again